# Egg Integrity/safety

Tags: food-safety

I cracked and egg to make scrambled eggs. the egg looked weird. The yolk was sort of orange, and looked kind of mosaic like, and seemed to be sort of congealed. I thought maybe it had frozen a bit on the top shelf of the frig, so I left the skillet on low to thaw it, added the milk, scrambled it, and even tho it never completely dissolves/mixes with the milk, it did so even less this time, and when I pulled the part up that hadn't mixed, it was a lot longer, thicker, just more massive than usual. Is there something wrong or unsafe about this egg?

Comment: Eggs are very cheap, when there is any doubt just throw it out. A picture in this case would definitely be worth a 1000 words.

Comment: When in doubt, don't use it.
But, on the other hand, freezing will usually mess up the texture of food without degrading the taste quality.

Answer (score 5):

There is no conclusive reason to say about safe or not either way.

When an egg is frozen, the yolk changes irreversibly. Even after thawing, its consistency is very different, much thicker than normal.

On the other hand, it may never have been frozen, but have been contaminated by something instead. Or it may have been frozen first and contaminated afterwards.

You cannot say what caused the visible, if it was freezing or microorganisms. So it is unsafe. As for there being something wrong, nobody can tell without a trip to the lab.